# Sort a list by the time of first appearance

Tags: python, sorting

I am interested in an algorithm that can sort a given list by the time of appearance in Python. For example:  [1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 4, 4, 7] -> [1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 4, 4, 7]. It seems that the build-in function with a custom key will do this job:

```
mylist = [1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 4, 4, 7]
sorted(mylist, key = lambda x: mylist.index(x))
```

However, I am more interested in implementing this myself. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: *"implementing this myself"*: how do you decide if some code is doing "this myself" and other code is not doing that?

Comment: should more be `mylist.count(x)` why the 4s are after the only 3 and 5, don't understand

Comment: @azro It's *their* question, not yours.

Answer (score 2):

A really fun way:

```
mylist.reverse()
for x in reversed(mylist):
    mylist.remove(x)
    mylist.append(x)
```

A boring but efficient way:

```
from collections import Counter

mylist = list(Counter(mylist).elements())
```

Comment: Quite interesting, and not too *boring* ... ;-)

Comment: Now I'm going to have your "really fun way" in the head until I finally take a pen and paper and work it out.

Comment: @Stef Yes, I think it's a nice little puzzle. I believe I originally came up with it to spite the people who repeat the "don't modify a list while you iterate it" mantra under questions that fail because of doing that poorly, as I'm exploiting what made them fail to do something useful :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple insertion sort-like algorithm that provides the correct output.

```
mylist = [1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 4, 4, 7]
def sort(lst):
    start = 0
    while start < len(lst):
        num = lst[start]
        end = len(lst) - 1
        while end > start:
            if lst[end] == num:
                del lst[end]
                start += 1
                lst.insert(start,num)
            else:
                end -= 1
        start += 1
    print(lst)
sort(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation can be done with the following algorithm:

1. Count the occurrence of each number and store it into a dictionary
2. Create another list holding the elements with their first appearance.
3. Print this list

And the code for this algorithm is:

```
lst = [1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 4, 4, 7]

d = {}
for e in lst:
    d[e] = d.get(e, 0) + 1

ans_lst = []
for e in lst:
    while d[e]:
        ans_lst.append(e)
        d[e] -= 1
print(ans_lst) # outputs: [1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 4, 4, 7]
```

This solution is having worst case time complexity `O(n)`
Whereas, the `sorted()` function has worst case time complexity of `O(nlogn)`

And your code will have a worst case time complexity of O(n<sup>2</sup>). As pointed out by [Kelly Bundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy)

> Because the index function is O(n) and they call it for each of the n elements

Comment: Their solution with `sorted` isn't O(nlogn), though.

Comment: @KellyBundy then?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @KellyBundy I mean worst case time complexity of any code having `sorted` function is O(nlogn)

Comment: That's not true, their code is only O(n²).

Comment: Can you explain how is it O(n²)? I can't find a reason for that..

Comment: Because the `index` function is O(n) and they call it for each of the n elements.